# Giving parameters to php with RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess

I need a RewriteRule to call a php file with parameters specified in the URL entred

ex :
if the url entered
http://www.example.com/folder1/sub1

to make it call go.php?p1=folder1&p2=sub1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)?/(.*) /go.php?p1=$1&p2=$2
```

Where `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`,`!-d` tell `mod_rewrite` to apply the rule just to paths not mapped to existing files and directories.

See also the [official documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond).

Comment: Your answer affected all real folders in the site , can you make it only working with go.php

Comment: when trying to give p1=bro&p2=sub1 .. Not Found

The requested URL /bro/sub2 was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: Sorry I forgot a couple of `!`